# Sum elements of matrix using threading

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading, matrix, parallel-processing

Using `threading` library, which would be the best way to sum ​​all the elements of an `matrix` using parallel programming?

I'm still getting in parallel programming and am a little confused. I tried to create a thread for each row of the matrix, but did not yield much difference in time compared to the sequential form. Tested on a `5000x5000` matrix with random numbers `0-100`.

If anyone can give me any tips of what to do!

Note: I do not want code!

Comment: _"I tried to create a thread for each row of the matrix, but did not yield much difference in time compared to the sequential form."_ Yes, for typical Python implementations, this is because the Global Interpreter Lock prevents multiple threads from running simultaneously. The `threading` library will almost never improve the speed of your program. Try `multiprocessing` instead, which is not affected by the GIL.

Comment: @Kevin It is what I should use threading library! But the way I did can be considered parallel?

Comment: Honestly you're probably best just using `numpy`, which is implemented in C (or FORTRAN?) and will blow the water out of most pure Python solutions, even those that properly use parallel processing.

Comment: _"the way I did can be considered parallel?"_ Yes, your approach is parallel. You just won't get good performance out of it, due to the technical limitations of the library.

Comment: @Kevin So thank you! If my teacher said to use this library is because he does not want a lot of improvement in time!